# Unwanted oscillations on op-amp output - capacitance issue?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, pcb-design

I have an op-amp ([THS4221DBVR](https://www.ti.com/product/THS4221/part-details/THS4221DBVR)) in a non-inverting amplifier configuration (gain = 1.39) to apply a tuning voltage to a VCO. The non-inverting input of the op-amp, for now, is just a DC voltage. I've confirmed on an oscilloscope that this input voltage, as well as the power supply voltage (VS+ = 12V with .1uF decoupling cap, VS- is grounded), are very clean DC signals. This is supposed to yield an output which is also a clean DC signal, but instead I get large (6V) fast (30MHz) oscillations on top of a DC signal.

I suspect the issue is related to some stray capacitances from the PCB. This is supported by the fact that I can change the amplitude of the oscillations by probing the board with a multimeter, or even just holding the probe tips near the board. The design schematic, PCB layout, and observed oscillations are attached below. There is a ground plane .29mm below the op-amp section of the PCB, and a ground fill on the top layer with .4mm isolation. I've been told Vtune (the VCO pin which the op-amp is driving) can be modeled as a 215pF load. When I place a 15nF capacitor between Vtune and GND, the oscillations vanish, but I worry that this will decrease the responsiveness of the circuit to changes in the input voltage.

My question is, how might I eliminate these oscillations while keeping the circuit responsive to changes on a ~100ns timescale? Do I want to get rid of all of the GND planes near the op-amp, or add a resistor somewhere to suppress the oscillations? Any ideas would be appreciated, but it may be some time before I can have another PCB manufactured.

[image: Schematic for the op-amp controlling the VCO]

[image: PCB layout for the op-amp]

[image: Observed oscillations]

Comment: That's actually a pretty good PCB layout. I get so used to seeing beginners' bad layouts on here that it's a surprise to see one that looks properly done!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to isolate the capacitance with a series resistor, just as it suggests in the datasheet. There are other ways that are more complex, but see  if this will work:

[image]

Add a resistor, perhaps 49.9Ω or 100Ω across a cut trace where 'X' marks the cut. The resulting pole is at ~15MHz or half that so still pretty high, and if the load does not represent too low a resistance relative to the added resistor it won't affect the DC voltage at the load much.

Comment: Spehro beat me to the answer.  Note that if you really are just charging up a capacitance, and there is no leakage path to ground, then you're not losing any precision.  If there _is_ leakage, then you can do some quick analysis and see if you're losing _enough_ precision to care.

Comment: I managed to make the cut and solder a 47ohm resistor across the gap. This seems to have eliminated the oscillations! One odd thing to note though: the oscillations come back if I touch the non-inverting input with any kind of probe or wire. I don't _need_ to probe this port, so I'll accept the answer as-is, but for the sake of stability in the future, would it be wise to additionally reduce the feedback resistors as @tesla23 suggests?

Comment: Yes, it would be wise. Those values are quite high for a 230MHz GBW amplifier.

Answer (score 4):

If Spehro's answer doesn't fix it, look at the stray capacitance at the inverting input.  If there was 5pF to ground at this node,  then 3k/5pF gives a pole at 10MHz, and could easily make the feedback loop unstable.  With a groundplane only 0.29mm below the traces, and the long trace on the inverting input, this could easily be causing instability.  Try reducing the feedback resistors or add some capacitive compensation.

For more details, see (for example): [www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-257.pdf](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-257.pdf)

Comment: I'm not super familiar with op-amp response theory, could you clarify what you mean by "capacitive compensation"? Is this just a capacitor between the non-inverting input and ground, and if so, would it reduce the responsiveness of the circuit?

Comment: I've added a link to an app note about stability for high-speed op amps